# How To Deal With HTML Response from the API in Volley

Tags: android, html, api, android-volley

**I am getting raw html full page data in my api request response. and I want to show them in webview or any pdf viewer. Already tried to show them in webview but didnt work for me beacuse of token issue. Any Better Way or any suggestion to handle this?**

[image: Response]

Comment: better than what? you didn't provide your way ... also asking for "better" is opinion based

Comment: @Selvin Just Edited. Please Check. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = //your url will be here

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String response) -> {

            Log.e("loadData: ",response);

            if(response != null){
                Response = response;

                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        System.out.println("Response" + response);

                        //webView.loadData(response,"text/html","utf-8");
                        //webView.loadData(response, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

                        ****//here i used the response to load in a webview!****

                        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, response, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                    }
                },2000);
            }

        }, error -> {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Authorization", token);
                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RiderPringtinActivity.this);
        queue.add(request);
```